# Replace content of selected cells, each getting different new content

Tags: notebooks, cells

Let's say I select 2 different cells and then attempt to replace their content using `NotebookWrite` inside a button.  How might I replace each cell's content individually instead of the current functionality I am getting.

```
Button["Write", NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], "Write"]]
Dynamic[Refresh[NotebookRead[SelectedNotebook[]],UpdateInterval -> 1]]
```

[image]

When I click on the `Write` button, only the last selected `Cell` gets replaced.

[image]

Is there a safe technique to replace each cell with unique content?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is very straightforward in v9 using `Cells` and `CellObject`.  Let's start with a notebook with a disjoint selection of the type you're describing:

```
nb = NotebookPut[
  Notebook[{
    Cell["a", CellTags -> "x"],
    Cell["b"], 
    Cell["c", CellTags -> "x"]}]];
NotebookFind[nb, "x", All, CellTags]
```

Now, we can get `CellObject`s for the selected cells by using `Cells`.

```
cells = Cells[NotebookSelection[nb]]
```

`NotebookWrite` allows you to overwrite any given `CellObject`.

```
NotebookWrite[First[cells], Cell["d"]]
NotebookWrite[Last[cells], Cell["e"]]
```

And this `NotebookWrite` operation can be done regardless of where the selection is at the time.  If you want to manipulate a notebook without having to fiddle with selections, `CellObject` is a very powerful tool and worth further exploration.